Create DevOps cycle in TikZ
My goal is to create a DevOps cycle in Tikz with the established infinity layout, like this one or the one on this page.
I started by using the wheelchart package, but I can't get the formular for plotting right.
However, I'm not firm on using the wheelchart package, only requirement is it has to be in TikZ/pgfplots.
Here is what I have so far:
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{wheelchart}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{DevOpsLightBlue}{RGB}{153, 204, 255}
\definecolor{DevOpsDarkBlue}{RGB}{0, 111, 192}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\sffamily
\wheelchart[
    arc data=\WCvarB,
    arc data angle shift=7,
    arc data expand=f,
    arc data pos=0.5,
    arc data style={text color=white},
    data=,
    gap=0.05,
    slices arrow={1}{0},
    slices style=\WCvarA,
    value=1,
]{%
  DevOpsLightBlue/Plan,
  DevOpsLightBlue/Code,
  DevOpsLightBlue/Build,
  DevOpsLightBlue/Test,
  DevOpsDarkBlue/Release,
  DevOpsDarkBlue/Deploy,
  DevOpsDarkBlue/Operate,
  DevOpsDarkBlue/Monitor%
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

Resulting in:


Do you mean the cross over like in $\infty$ ? // If so see p. 35 in the manual. Looks like all you need to do is to define such a curve using polar coordinates first and work from there. https://ctan.mirror.norbert-ruehl.de/graphics/pgf/contrib/wheelchart/wheelchart.pdf (in section 4 "Keys")

Have a look at Lemniscate, e.g. here: https://www.mathnasium.com/math-centers/hinsdale/news/lemniscate

Exactly, however, polar coordinates where never my strong suit and I wasn't able to figure out how to convert the polar form of the lemniscate to the syntax wheelchart requires

Page 35. Not much magic to it once you „steel“ the known formula.

That's exactly what I'm struggling with and why I asked for help

Let me refine. I assume you can copy the code from p. 35 and run it. I assume you can find the various formulas for a Lemniscate, e.g. here https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Lemniscate.html . If so ... why can't you copy the formula into wheelchart?

The answer below uses the wheelchart package, which I wrote.
The command \wheelchart is used 4 times. The first one draws the part of the circle at the left, the second one draws the part of the circle at the right and the last two draw the crossing in the middle.
The key gap does not apply if a plot is used thus \gap has to be taken into account in the domain for the third and fourth \wheelchart and for the key value in the fourth \wheelchart.
The plots in the third and fourth \wheelchart require only 2 samples thus the key samples=2 is given to reduce the file size.
The fourth \wheelchart has an empty middle part by using the key slices style{2}={fill=none}.
\documentclass[border=6pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{wheelchart}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\sffamily
\def\r{1}%inner radius
\def\R{2}%outer radius
\def\gap{0.05}
\definecolor{DevOpsLightBlue}{RGB}{153,204,255}
\definecolor{DevOpsDarkBlue}{RGB}{0,111,192}
\pgfkeys{
  /wheelchart,
  arc data=\WCvarA,
  arc data angle shift=10,
  arc data pos=0.5,
  arc data style={text color=white},
  data=,
  gap=\gap,
  radius={\r}{\R},
  slices arrow={1}{0},
  value=1
}
\wheelchart[
  arc data dir={\WCmidangle<180?-1:1},
  at={({-(\r+\R)/sqrt(2)},0)},
  domain=45:315,
  middle=Dev,
  middle style={DevOpsLightBlue,font=\huge},
  slices style=DevOpsLightBlue
]{%
  CODE,
  BUILD,
  TEST%
}
\wheelchart[
  arc data dir={\WCmidangle<180?1:-1},
  at={({(\r+\R)/sqrt(2)},0)},
  middle=Ops,
  middle style={DevOpsDarkBlue,font=\huge},
  slices style=DevOpsDarkBlue,
  start angle=135,
  total angle=270
]{%
  DEPLOY,
  OPERATE,
  MONITOR%
}
\pgfkeys{
  /wheelchart,
  arc data angle shift=0.2,
  domain=\gap-(\r+\R)/2:(\r+\R)/2-\gap,%the key gap does not apply if a plot is used thus \gap has to be taken into account
  radius={(\r-\R)/2}{(\R-\r)/2},
  samples=2%the plots below require only 2 samples and specifying this key reduces the file size
}
\wheelchart[
  plot={{#1*cos(45)+#2*cos(135)},{#1*sin(45)+#2*sin(135)}},
  slices style=DevOpsDarkBlue
]{%
  RELEASE%
}
\wheelchart[
  arc data dir=-1,
  plot={{#1*cos(135)+#2*cos(45)},{#1*sin(135)+#2*sin(45)}},
  slices end arc{1}={0}{0},
  slices start arc{3}={0}{0},
  slices style=DevOpsLightBlue,
  slices style{2}={fill=none},
  value{list}={\r-2*\gap,\R-\r+2*\gap,\r-2*\gap}
  %the length is \r+\R-2*\gap
  %the middle overlapping part has thickness \R-\r and including the gap this is \R-\r+2*\gap
]{%
  ,
  ,
  PLAN%
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



Thank you! This is exactly what I'm looking for! And way more complicated than I expected
